# Can I power multiple devices from one output of a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, battery-charging

I am working on an LED project so I need to buy a power supply for powering some ESP32s and some LED strips.

During my research I saw Philips Hue's 3 output adapter, with which if you want to power more than one device you can use one adapter to power all.

I want to design an adapter like that which has 2 outputs for LEDs and ESPs and maybe add 2 USB ports to charge phones.

I found a power supply which has AC input and 5V 16A output.

This is power supply I found:

[image]

Also I drew a simple diagram (very simple) of what I want to do:

[image]

The LEDs consume a maximum of 3.6A at 5V, the ESP32 consumes not so much (not sure about maximum) and this power supply can give up to 16A.

All devices work at 5V.

Also I want to know if I can do this do I need anything like current protection module (I don't know if  there is anything like that) or a current limiter for USB output to charge phone. Is there any risk to phone?

Comment: Hi there.  Hit the edit button and add the specs of the power supply you're asking about.

Comment: Not sufficient info. What are the output voltage and output current of the adapter? Is the adapter constant-voltage or constant-current output? `So leds are consuming maximum 3,6A` at what voltage?

Comment: not sure about constant voltage or constant current. I wast know there is something like that. but it have 5v 16A output as seller's say. and leds consuming at 5v to

Comment: Totally possible if you know anything about electronics. You are just connecting things in parallel. The only risk is a bigger spark if you accidentally short something out, so you might want to add a fuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this will work, however:

Better get a good quality power supply (brands like Meanwell) than no-name junk. These individually addressable LEDs draw current pulses. Some cheap power supplies have trouble regulating the voltage, or they will emit audible whine, which is annoying. Some junk brands are quite dangerous and omit stuff you really want to have, like proper creepage distance between primary and secondary, or proper fusing, or filtering, or proper cooling. It isn't worth risking fire or electric shock to save ten bucks on a power supply. Also a good quality supply will be more efficient, so you can be proud to Save The Planet™.

If you use a power supply that is quite powerful, like 16A, then you need to make sure the wires you use won't melt and cause a fire in case there is a short somewhere. Better pick a power supply with hiccup overcurrent protection that will shut down in case there is a short and periodically try to restart, rather than a dumb power supply that will just use a current-limit and sustain 16A through your wires.

You will connect ESP32 ground to LED ground, and both grounds to power supply. Make sure this connection is absolutely solid. If the LED ground gets disconnected from the supply, but ESP32 ground remains connected to supply and LED, then the full LED current would go through ESP32 PCB, which means bad news. Basically, this is a possibility if your ground wires make a triangle.

Keep wiring short, clean, and twisted. ESP32 emits quite fast signals to control the LEDs (I'm assuming something like WS2812) so you should twist that wire with the LED ground and supply. If the control wire makes a large loop it will have extra inductance, signal integrity will be bad, and the LEDs won't get proper commands.

Put a 2A polyswitch or fuse on the USB ports. If the USB cable gets damaged through repeated bending and has an internal short, you don't want 16A running in it and melting both the connector and the cable.

Also, on the AC mains part, make sure you do it up to code.

Comment: thenk you very much for your enlightening explanation and guidince.It will be very helpfull. I will pay attention all you have said